# Facebook API: Can I use an expired long-lived access token to get a new one?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I'm aware that I can exchange/extend a non-expired short-lived access token with a long-lived access token using [this method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending). I'm also aware that I can use a non-expired long-lived access token to generate a new long-lived access token using [this method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#long-via-code).

**My question is**: can I use an ***expired*** long-lived access token to get a new long-lived access token using either of the methods linked above?

Note: I haven't been able to answer myself because I don't yet have a long-lived access token that is 60 days old, I'll try to make one, store it away, and try both methods after 60 days, if no answer was given to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use an expired or otherwise invalid access token to fetch a new one - if that were possible it would make the expiration or invalidation moot